# Oracle DMP having multiple errors and failing

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to run a simple dump command on my Oracle 11g Database and It is giving me three errors and then failing.

Here is the command that I am running minus the obvious security information:

```
expdp test/test@db1 directory=dpump dumpfile=expdat.dmp schemas=quantum REUSE_DUMPFILES=Y
```

This command was just run earlier today and it worked. I'm writing a python script to keep my development database up to date from the production db automatically.

Thus, I'm running the command to see all of the output so I can code my script to wait to move on until its completed. I am also not currently using python to run the command, im simply pasting it into the terminal.

output:

```
[oracle@db1a ~]$ expdp test/test@db1 directory=dpump dumpfile=expdat.dmp schemas=quantum REUSE_DUMPFILES=Y

Export: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Wed Sep 24 13:33:17 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Real Application Clusters and Automatic Storage Management options
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31687: error creating worker process  with worker id 1
ORA-31687: error creating worker process  with worker id 1
ORA-31688: Worker process  failed during startup.
```

Comment: You connected as the same `test` user and exported the `quantum` schema, when it worked? Does `test` have `export any` privs? Did it create a log file - I suspect not, but if it did, does it contain any more information?

Comment: its not really under the user test, I put that there to not have my login information.